# FNV1A_64 don't match

Tags: python, mysql, hash, fnv

I'm trying 3 different implementation of **FNV1A_64** hash.

1) [Maatkit](http://code.google.com/p/maatkit/)

```
SELECT FNV1A_64('1')
```

**Result**: *-5808609649712063748*

2) [pyhash](http://code.google.com/p/pyfasthash/)

```
import pyhash
hasher = pyhash.fnv1a_64()
print hasher('1')
```

**Result**: *53876069782339L*

3) [fnv](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/src/fnv/)

```
./fnv1a64 -s 1
```

**Result**: *0xaf63ac4c86019afc* (12638134423997487000 decimal)

Why all the results are different ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL and the command line program gave you the same result. One just printed a signed number and the other printed a hex representation of the same number.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('q', -5808609649712063748)
'\xfc\x9a\x01\x86L\xacc\xaf'
>>> struct.unpack('Q', _)
(12638134423997487868L,)
>>> 0xaf63ac4c86019afc == _[0]
True
```

Python, however, requires `FNV1A_64_INIT` as it's not passed by default.

```
>>> FNV1A_64_INIT = 0xcbf29ce484222325
>>> import pyhash
>>> hasher = pyhash.fnv1a_64()
>>> hasher('1', seed=FNV1A_64_INIT)
12638134423997487868L
>>> _ == 0xaf63ac4c86019afc
True
```